# SearchFilter Logical Operators AND and Or

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

How to Perform SearchFilter Logical Operator `AND` and `OR` Programatically based on the operation selected by user??

If the user gives a select like this `"[To]ContainsSubstring'Ram' OR [To]containssubstring'lak'`  how to perform it?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the individual filters as Expressions and then combine them based on the user's choices.

---

EDIT: What i am proposing is to create predicates (which i understand are deprecated now and the recommendation is to use Func which is basically the same thing) and then combine them into an expression and apply it to your list that has to be fildered.

An example i found here: [Combine Multiple Predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248232/combine-multiple-predicates)

---

What i have done in the past is to combine predicates based on user's choice and then compile them into an expression and then use that as the parameter to the Linq Where extension method.

So, an example (not sure if it will compile wrote it right now:) :

```
List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
List<Func<Customer,bool>> predicateList = new List<Func<Customer,bool>>();

if(/*user choice condition*/)
{
    predicateList.Add(c => c.Name.Contains("test"));
}
if (/*user choice condition*/)
{
    predicateList.Add(c => c.Name.Contains("test") || c.Description.Contains("buyer"));
}
//etc.


Expression<Func<IWorkItem, bool>> filterExpression = c => whereClausePredicates.All(pred => pred(c));
var filteredCustomers = list.Where(filterExpression.Compile());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply dutzu.Can u tel me any examples for it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply dutzu.How can we filter items in the publicfolders based on there DateTime Sent and Recieved??I tried this `filter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeSent, "28/08/12 6:34:06 PM");'...But error generating.Error-The specified value is invalid for property...i have specified the value in correct format.

Comment: @user1891567 when comparing datetime you cannot rely on strings, i hope that the logic you have there first parses the string you sent to DateTime and then compares the two