# Advanced Search using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to implement **Advanced Search** in my ASP.NET MVC Application, where user can select 1 or more criteria for the product search.

Let's say I have these criterias: *Color*, *Size*, *Price Range*.

This is as far as I get till now

```
ProductSizeList = db.ProductSizes.Where(ProductSize =>
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductColorId) || ProductSize.Product.ProductColors.Where(a => a.ColorID == IntColorId).Any())
    ).GroupBy(x => x.ProductID).Select(Grouped => Grouped.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

I have a *many-to-many* relationship between `Product` and `Color` tables, and `ProductColor` is the one linking them. Same thing with `Product`, `ProductSize`, `Size` tables.

The code is working perfectly with the `Size`, and `Price Range`. The problem with the `Color`, because `.Any()` returns when it finds the first `Product`. If There is more than one `Product`, it only returns the first one.

So, I want to know if there is another *method*, or another way to be able to get all products with the specified color.

I searched a lot, and know that I can build Where Clause Dynamically, but I think it would be too much work for my requirements. If there is a simple fix for this I would be more than happy.

**Edit**

I removed the *working-as-wanted* code as suggested by @Jeroen, and left the one I want to fix.

**Solved**

I fixed it, thanks to combining @jason and @Marlon answers. I'll put the solution in a separate answer. I just want to understand 2 points:

- Why it only worked Correctly when I based my query on Product?
- Why `.Distinct()` didn't do any thing, and I got duplicated products.

Comment: You probably should look into Predicates (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710395/3951051) and maybe chain them. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248232/combine-multiple-predicates)

Comment: It would help if you trimmed down the code to just the actual lambda (part) you're having problems with, and include some minimal bit of set-up code to repro the issue. Currently I feel there's a lot of code bits distracting from the actual problem you're having.

Comment: I guess you filter your results not by calling Any(), but here: Grouped.FirstOrDefault(). And by the way, you can call Any directly with predicate and without Where clause: Any(a => a.ColorID == IntColorId)

Comment: @FireAlkazar This code discard duplicated results `GroupBy(x => x.ProductID).Select(Grouped => Grouped.FirstOrDefault())`, with`Size` and `Price Range`, it returns all results without duplication. Thanks for the `.Any()` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this. It uses IQueryable to let you more easily construct your conditions before executing against the database when `ToList` is called.

```
var query = db.ProductSizes.AsQueryable();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductColorId) == false)
    query = query.Where(ProductSize => ProductSize.Product.ProductColors.Any(a => a.ColorID == IntColorId))
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SizeId) == false)
    query = query.Where(ProductSize => ProductSize.Size.Id == IntSizeId);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(From) == false)
    query = query.Where(ProductSize => ProductSize.Price >= DecimalFrom);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(To) == false)
    query = query.Where(ProductSize => ProductSize.Price <= DecimalTo);
var ProductSizeList = query
    .Select(ProductSize => ProductSize.ProductID)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get how this would differ from my solution. `.Any()` would return once the condition is fulfilled, and would return the first product only.

Comment: The `.Any()` here returns true only if colors linked to a product that is also linked to the ProductSize in your query. It respects the products that match your other conditions. Perhaps the non-desirable results are due to the `FirstOrDefault` in the `GroupBy` or the From/To that wasn't really separated in your original query or because you have other product sizes linked to products you didn't expect with matching colors? Without seeing your data, it's difficult to guess what's wrong here, but this approach should be fine. I've used it many times.

Answer (score 1):

Try to base your query on Product, instead of ProductSize: (You didn't say , so i'm supposing Size and Price are in ProductSize objects).

```
var query = db.Product.AsQueryable();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductColorId) == false)
    query = query.Where(product => product.ProductColors.Where(a => a.ColorID == IntColorId).Any());
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SizeId) == false)
    query = query.Where(product => product.Sizes.Where(s => s.Size_Id == IntSizeId));

(...)

var ProductSizeList = query
    .Select(product => product.ProductID)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

I prefere Jason W's approach instead of putting everything in one query, because in the last the 'or' in the middle of the query would ignore any index in the database.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get how this would differ from my solution. `.Any()` would return once the condition is fulfilled, and would return the first product only.

Comment: Any is inside Product.Where, so it would be called for each product.And basing your query on Product entity, you wouldn't need to have a Group by.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
var query = db.Products.AsQueryable();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductColorId) == false)
    query = query.Where(Product => Product.ProductColors.Any(a => a.ColorID == IntColorId));
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SizeId) == false)
    query = query.Where(Product => Product.ProductSizes.Any(a => a.SizeID == IntSizeId));
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(From) == false)
    query = query.Where(Product => Product.ProductSizes.Any(a => a.Price >= DecimalFrom));
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(To) == false)
    query = query.Where(Product => Product.ProductSizes.Any(a => a.Price <= DecimalTo));
var ProductsList = query
    .Select(ProductSize => ProductSize)
    .GroupBy(x => x.id).Select(Grouped => Grouped.FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

I based my query on `Product`, and used `GroupBy` to remove duplicate results instead of `Distinct`.