# Combining Predicates in post .Net 2.0

Tags: c#, predicate, func

What is the way of combining predicates like we used do for `Expression.AndAlso`

I have a predicate

```
Predicate<Foo> predicate = p1 => (p1.IsActive) && p1.Type != "BR";
```

and

```
Predicate<Foo> datePredicate = p1 => (p1.Year) == DateTime.Now.Year;
```

Based on some condition I want to combine both so that resultant predicate can be passed to a method which accepts single predicate parameter.

```
predicate = predicate.????(datePredicate);
```

so what is the way to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1248263/106159

Comment: You can also take a look at LinqKit (you will need to reference it). Scroll to combining expressions: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

Comment: Predicate<Foo> datePredicateAnd = p =>(predicate(p) && datePredicate(p))

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I have seen that and its for .Net 2.0 when predicate class was not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine predicates as below

```
Predicate<Foo> datePredicateAnd = p =>(predicate(p) && datePredicate(p));
```

Comment: Even though this will also work `predicate = p => predicate(p) && datePredicate(p);` but this will cause StackOverflow Exception as it will try to call itself resulting in StackOverflow. A perfect example of `Access to modified Closure.`